# Using policykit+dbus instead of gksu to run graphical application

Tags: python, linux, root, sudo, dbus

I'm searching for a command that does gksu or beesu job, but depends on policykit.

The policykit and dbus documentation is somehow very complicated and not clear.

I found "pkexec" but it shows errors when trying to run a graphical application

```
pkexec gedit
```

results:

```
(gedit:7243): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you want answering, could you clarify?

Comment: running a graphical application with root privileges in linux. But I dont want to use gksu command since it doesnt work in all distros, instead I am trying to use policykit.
this command "pkexec test.py" results
pkexec gedit results: (gedit:7243): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `action definition file` in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` written in `XML`.

Copy this to `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.example.gedit`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
 "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>

  <action id="com.example.gedit">
    <message gettext-domain="gedit">Authentication is required to run gedit as root</message>
    <icon_name>accessories-text-editor</icon_name>
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
    </defaults>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/gedit</annotate>
    <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
  </action>

</policyconfig>
```

The value `org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui = true` will allow gedit to connect to your Xorg server. It'll automatically pass `XAUTHORITY` and `DISPLAY` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of graphical programs need dbus so even if you manage to run it, it might fail.
For gnome programs at least following variables need to be set 
`'SESSION_MANAGER', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS', 'DISPLAY',                  'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID', 'XAUTHORITY'`. For kde programs you need `'SESSION_MANAGER', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS', 'DISPLAY', 'KDE_FULL_SESSION', 'XAUTHORITY'`
I thing pkexec needs at least XAUTHORITY and DISPLAY to be able to connect to xorg server.